# MembershipUser business object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a separate project that contains all of my business objects.  One of the business objects, `User`, holds login information and I want to convert it to be a `MembershipUser` object (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx)).  However, `MembershipUser` object requires `System.Web`.  I don't want to add that reference to my BO project.  How do I use my business object as a `MembershipUser` without the dependency living in my BO project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't, at least not directly.  The only way I can think of is to write a wrapper class in your web project which inherits from MembershipUser and takes in one of your BOs as a constructor param, then delegates all its functionality to the BO.  It's not pretty, but it's pretty much the only way I'm aware of to solve your problem.